# Why do I have extra so much space between my side bar and my content?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, html

I've boiled my layout down to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXzjX/4/) or the [full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/tXzjX/2/embedded/result/) version

I am having two problems. The first, is that space between the side bar and the content is very large. I want them to be spaced as normal. In my case, I'm expecting the side bar to be `span2` in size, my main content to be `span7` in size and then a right hand column to be `span3`.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
      <div class="well sidebar-nav-fixed">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
            ...other links ...
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span7 span-fixed-sidebar">
        <div id="world-map" style="display:block;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12" id="country-info">
                <h2 id="country-info-header">
                    The Detail Header
                </h2>
                <p id="country-info-summary">
                    A set of summary information. A short paragraph of text.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, I'm getting a result with a huge gap between my sidebar and my content (the red box), and the right hand content is on the left hand side and under my sidebar. How can I fix this layout?

[image]

Comment: You have classes but no external CSS?

Comment: Try to remove the `span-fixed-sidebar` you have on `span-fixed-sidebar`. I think they might be positioned fixed from the same point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to experiment with Bootstraps `offset` classes. I made you a quick example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tXzjX/5/

Your `position:fixed` takes the element out of the natural flow of the page, and in a way "resets" the columns on the grid. Using Bootstrap's `offset` classes can counteract that issue. Check here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem under "Offsetting Columns".

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just reduce the margin size like so:

```
.row-fluid > .span-fixed-sidebar {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

as that seems to move the red bar in nicely

EDIT: I have had a play about and come up with a slightly simpler looking code with what I think is the effect you require with a bit of tweaking. http://jsfiddle.net/bmgh1985/UeFRa/

Comment: Ah. I did not spot the text underneath in the fiddle. Would using clear:left and a relative position work for you?